# After installing ubuntu-gnome-desktop i can't remote destop to vps

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, xrdp

I install **ubuntu-gnome-desktop** on my Ubuntu16.4 using putty and after installation completed , i can't remote to VPS using remote desktop.

I try this command to install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

when connect to VPS appear this massage as normal situation and after few seconds session will closed.

[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW9zi.png)

[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCxFs.png)

after this issue i purge the **ubuntu-gnome-desktop** and **gnome-shell** by using this commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-shell
```

and purge the xrdp and install again by this commands :

**purge:**

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge xrdp
```

**install:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

**but the issue not solved please if  anybody can solve this replay my post**